# Error in metpy.calc.wind_direction with era5 data

Tags: dask, python-xarray, metpy

I downloaded Era5 U and V wind components from era-5 and I am using xarray to read the .nc file and select several lat lon points from the data. After i need to calculate wind speed and direction using metpy.calc function:

```
ds = xr.open_mfdataset('ERA5_u10_*.nc',combine='by_coords').metpy.parse_cf()
dv = xr.open_mfdataset('ERA5_v10_*.nc',combine='by_coords').metpy.parse_cf()
#direction =mpcalc.wind_direction(ds['u10'],dv['v10'])
#dd=mpcalc.wind_direction(ds.u10,dv.v10)
locations=[]
k=0
u10 = []
v10=[]
speed=[]
direction=[]
u100 = []
v100=[]
for i,j in zip(lats,lons):
    stations_u=ds.sel(longitude=j,latitude=i,method='nearest')
    stations_v=dv.sel(longitude=j,latitude=i,method='nearest')

    u10.append(stations_u.u10)### mudar variavel
    v10.append(stations_v.v10)### mudar variavel
    speed.append(mpcalc.wind_speed(stations_u.u10,stations_v.v10))
    direction.append(mpcalc.wind_direction(stations_u.u10,stations_v.v10))
```

Wind speed works with no problem, but wind direction raises an error:

```
runfile('/mnt/data1/ERA5/wind/untitled0.py', wdir='/mnt/data1/ERA5/wind')
Found valid latitude/longitude coordinates, assuming latitude_longitude for projection grid_mapping variable
Found valid latitude/longitude coordinates, assuming latitude_longitude for projection grid_mapping variable
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/python/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/array/core.py", line 1615, in __setitem__
    y = where(key, value, self)

  File "/usr/local/python/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/array/routines.py", line 1382, in where
    return elemwise(np.where, condition, x, y)

  File "/usr/local/python/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/array/core.py", line 4204, in elemwise
    broadcast_shapes(*shapes)

  File "/usr/local/python/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/array/core.py", line 4165, in broadcast_shapes
    "shapes {0}".format(" ".join(map(str, shapes)))

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (262968,) (nan,) (262968,)


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/mnt/data1/ERA5/wind/untitled0.py", line 40, in <module>
    direction.append(mpcalc.wind_direction(stations_u.u10,stations_v.v10))

  File "/usr/local/python/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/metpy/xarray.py", line 1206, in wrapper
    result = func(*bound_args.args, **bound_args.kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/python/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/metpy/units.py", line 246, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/python/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/metpy/calc/basic.py", line 104, in wind_direction
    wdir[mask] += 360. * units.deg

  File "/usr/local/python/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pint/quantity.py", line 1868, in __setitem__
    self._magnitude[key] = factor.magnitude

  File "/usr/local/python/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/array/core.py", line 1622, in __setitem__
    ) from e

ValueError: Boolean index assignment in Dask expects equally shaped arrays.
Example: da1[da2] = da3 where da1.shape == (4,), da2.shape == (4,) and da3.shape == (4,).
```

If i try to calculate Wdir with only 1 element in U and in V, surprisingly it works:

```
mpcalc.wind_direction(stations_u.u10[0],stations_v.v10[0]).values
Out[12]: array(173.41553, dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`metpy.calc.wind_direction` is unfortunately [known not to work with Dask arrays](https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/issues/1479)--and in fact many places in MetPy don't work well with Dask, though we [definitely want to](https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/issues/1479). For now, to use `wind_direction` you'll need to turn `stations_u`, etc. into standard numpy arrays using e.g. `.compute()`.

Comment: Thanks it works ! And it doesn´t take too much time :)

Answer (score 0):

Thaks for your reply! Yeh it makes sense...

The dataarrays i am working with are very big, so i need to keep it as a dataArray because copying it to a normal np array would use more memory that what i have xD
I eventually tried the calculation with statins_u as both u and v, and surprisingly it works:

```
mpcalc.wind_direction(stations_u.u10,stations_u.u10)## Heading ##
Out[7]: 
<xarray.DataArray 'sub-404afe706bcfce1f36810c70766c0647' (time: 262968)>
<Quantity(dask.array<sub, shape=(262968,), dtype=float32, chunksize=(87672,), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>, 'degree')>
Coordinates:
    longitude  float32 -7.1
    latitude   float32 43.8
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1990-01-01 ... 2019-12-31T23:00:00
```

why does it work in this case ? isn't metpy.calc_wind_direction using dask array in this case ?
i fell that there's something wrong with attributes names and units and pint, but cant understand what it is ...

Comment: I'm not sure why it works, but the fundamental problem is that dask doesn't support the following type of operation: `a[a > 2] += 4` (This fails without any MetPy or units.)