# metpy.calc.wind_direction ValueError: Boolean index assignment in Dask expects equally shaped arrays

Tags: metpy

I have several netCDF4 files containing different times and variables that I stacked in a unique xarray Dataset to compute different sounding parameters.

I have been able to use other metpy.calc operators, but can't manage to compute wind direction. The following is a simple version of my code:

```
#open datasets
    p_files = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(dirin), '*2019*')
    data=xarray.open_mfdataset(p_files,combine='by_coords',concat_dim="time")
    s_files= fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(dirin), '*2019*')
    dataSFC=xarray.open_mfdataset(s_files,combine='by_coords',concat_dim="time")


    data = data.metpy.parse_cf()
    dataSFC = dataSFC.metpy.parse_cf()
    
#Dataframe with events 
    df=pd.read_csv(dir_df+file)
    df=pd.DataFrame.to_numpy(df)
        
#lat lon index
    lat_data = df[n, 3]
    lon_data = df[n,4]
#time index
    time_data = df[n,5]
    time_data = np.datetime64(time_data)
#slice Dataset for lat, lon, time 
  slice_surf=dataSFC.sel(latitude=lat_data,longitude=lon_data,time=time_data,method='nearest')
  slice_press=data.sel(latitude=lat_data,longitude=lon_data,time=time_data,method='nearest')
                   
#obtain variables  
    temp = slice_press.variables['t']
    hum = slice_press.variables['r']
    u = slice_press.variables['u']
    v = slice_press.variables['v']
    z = slice_press.variables['z']
    q = slice_press.variables['q']
        
#Compute TEMP (C)
    temperatureC = (np.array(slice_press['t']) - 273.15)[::-1] 
            
#Compute Dewpoint from Rel Hum
    dewpoint1 = mpcalc.dewpoint_from_relative_humidity(slice_press['t'], slice_press['r']/100)
          
#Compute wind speed
    wind_speed = mpcalc.wind_speed(slice_press['u'], slice_press['v']) #wind velocity   
            
#Compute Wind dir
    wind_direction = mpcalc.wind_direction(uMS,vMS,convention='from') #wind dir
```

The error I am having only happens when trying to calculate the wind direction. I am able to compute wind speed from uMS and vMS and other previous variables such as dewpoint. The error is the following:

> ValueError: Boolean index assignment in Dask expects equally shaped
> arrays. Example: da1[da2] = da3 where da1.shape == (4,), da2.shape ==
> (4,) and da3.shape == (4,).

I have checked the shape of my uMS and vMS components and they look equally shaped arrays (20,0) and same type of data (xarray.core.dataarray.DataArray).

Comment: I think this answers your question? [Error in metpy.calc.wind\_direction with era5 data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374880/error-in-metpy-calc-wind-direction-with-era5-data)

Comment: Yes, this works! Thank you